# выполнение функции по истечению времени

Tags: c#, время

в моей программе есть функция,которая должна выполняться только в определенное время(дд/мм/гггг).Пользователь вводит дату,и только в это время функция выполняеться.
как реализовать таймер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одним из миллиона способов. Например, так:

```
async Task ExecuteAfter(DateTime when, Action function)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if (when > now)
        await Task.Delay(when - now);
    function();
}
```

---

Другой метод:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (when <= now)
{
    function();
}
else
{
    var milliseconds = (when - now).TotalMilliseconds;
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(milliseconds) { AutoReset = false };
    timer.Elapsed += (o, args) => { function(); timer.Stop(); timer.Dispose(); };
    // если вы пишете на WinForms, можете указать ещё
    // timer.SynchronizingObject = <any control>
    // чтобы вызов произошёл в UI-потоке
    timer.Start();
}
```

---

Ещё один:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (when <= now)
{
    function();
}
else
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        o => { function(); timer.Dispose(); },
        null,
        when - now,
        TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

---

Ещё один подход — использование синхронизационных примитивов и ожидание с таймаутом события, которое никогда не наступит. Например, при помощи семафора:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (when > now)
    using (var sema = new SemaphoreSlim(0))
        sema.Wait(when - now);
function();
```

(Не рекомендуется, блокирует текущий поток!)

---

Ещё один метод, использование потоков + `Sleep`. Не рекомендуется, т. к. блокирует поток, а это ненужный расход ресурсов. Наихудший метод — блокирование текущего потока:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (when > now)
    Thread.Sleep(when - now);
function();
```

Чуть лучше идея с выгрузкой в отдельный поток:

```
new Thread(() =>
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if (when > now)
            Thread.Sleep(when - now);
        function();
    }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

Ещё чуть-чуть лучше использовать thread pool (но всё равно плохо):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if (when > now)
            Thread.Sleep(when - now);
        function();
    });
```

Comment: Осторожнее с засыпанием более чем на 10 дней. При попытке уснуть на такой сверхдлительный промежуток времени поток может уже никогда не проснуться. Таймеры также могут не сработать. Ловил такой баг на XP SP3.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, это баг. Как раз хотел дописать метод, блокирующий поток. Текущие три метода вроде бы в эту проблему не влазят.

Comment: Сверхдолгие таймеры также не запустятся если в программе не будет никаких других таймеров.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я не вполне понял, что вы имеете в виду, покажете пример кода?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(20.0))` - и все, если никакой код не использует таймеры, этот таймер никогда более не отработает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, это выглядит как баг. А на современных системах вы такое воспроизводили?

Comment: Времени не было проверять :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov мне кажется что при длительном засыпании более разумно было бы использовать некий файл/бд если угодно. и раз в некий промежуток подтягивать данные из этого источника. например каждый час брать задания на текущий час. и запускать async методы с необходимой задержкой от текущего времени

Comment: @Bald56rus откуда взялся период в час? Почему не день? Почему не 20 дней? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov любой угодный Вам период времени который не означает *Сверхдолгий таймер* :)

Comment: @Bald56rus ну так значит, все равно надо держать в голове этот баг? Тогда в чем улучшение?

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну предложенным мной способом можно данный *баг* обойти, ну и как то контролировать, например что в *n* промежутке будет выполнено столько то тасков, при желании отменить удалив запись из бд. я подразумеваю что данных тасков может быть много и с разным временем отстрочки. так зачем их создавать сейчас, если можно ближе к необходимому моменту, раз в день/час/минуту/секунду как угодно. на истинность не претендую. скорее мысль в слух.

Comment: @Bald56rus баг можно обойти и без того, чтобы сначала сохранять все задачи в файл, а потом читать их оттуда обратно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня возникает только один вопрос, как быть если было создана куча тасков с отсрочкой выполнения и тут произошел *крах* приложения?! и можете привести пример как обойти *баг* про который Вы сами в коментах и сообщили. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Bald56rus баг обходится просто - ограничение интервала ожидания сверху и цикл. Если приложение было перезапущено - разумеется, задачи надо создать заново. Но зачастую пересоздание их заново куда проще, чем сохранение в БД и чтение обратно...

Comment: @Bald56rus: Ну, например так: http://pastebin.com/2X9btz5Y

Comment: @VladD, как-то у вас получилось, что Thread.Sleep не рекомендуется, а Wait на временном семафоре - нормально. Но ведь недостатки у этих способов - общие...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Да, я написал же вроде, что это не рекомендуется. // Дописал это более явно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Может быть, ваша проблема была в этом: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27995221/276994?

Comment: @VladD нет. Я ловил баг когда ждал int.MaxValue / 2 миллисекунд :-)